# Vim in /usr/local Keeps Getting Overwritten After apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, compiling, vim

I have manually compiled vim following the instructions on https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source. I changed the configure step to include `--prefix=/usr/local` and then ran make with `make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim80`.

Everything seems to work great. I see the `vim/` directory in `/usr/local/share` and it even is set as the "default" version of vim.

I've followed several different methods: [holding](https://superuser.com/questions/837649/prevent-apt-get-from-updating-a-package), and using [`--set-selections`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866880/apt-get-dist-upgrade-without-overwriting-my-self-compiled-vim) installing into `/usr/local` should be safe from having my compiled version of vim from being overwritten. However, every time I run `apt-get upgrade` I lose my version of vim.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you use the `checkinstall` method or the plain `install` method?

Comment: I used `checkinstall`

Comment: Even Synaptic's lock didn't work? And how did you upgrade afterwards, plain `apt-get upgrade` in a terminal?

Comment: I honestly didn't try that method because I don't have Synaptic installed. But yes just a plain `sudo apt-get upgrade` overwrote my compiled vim.